# Which variant should be used?

Tags: grammar

*The company was founded by a man who **has/had** been to Paris.*
What form should be used and why?

Comment: The man who _has_ been to Paris may have been there yesterday. The man who _had_ been to Paris, went there **before** founding the company, and his time there evidently influenced him in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The company was founded by a man who ***had** been* to Paris *[before he founded the company; this man can be still alive or already dead]*.

> The company was founded by a man who ***has** been* to Paris *[the founder is still alive; the fact that he has been to Paris is considered important in relation to the moment of speech: this is not someone who has never been to Paris; the moment of his going to Paris is not specified, it can be before or after the foundation of the company]*.

So depending on what you want to say, chose an option that suits best.